# PHP & MySQL - INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert data except if 2 fields exist in that row. Below is my current query that adds everything that works.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_sync_status (ghl_contact_email, ghl_contact_data, result, wp_user_id) VALUES ('$source->email', '$payload', 'success', $user->id)";
```

So I  tried the following to make it conditional:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_sync_status (ghl_contact_email, ghl_contact_data, result, wp_user_id) VALUES ('$source->email', '$payload', 'success', $user->id) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM contact_sync_status WHERE ghl_contact_email = '$source->email' AND wp_user_id = $user->id)";
```

But i receive a SQL syntax error because it seems that WHERE NOT EXISTS can't be used with INSERT. I've also tried a unique index in the DB but this is not an option.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005).

Comment: Doing a completely separate query to see if it exists first would work.

Comment: Why is a unique index not an option? This is the accepted (and really, the only effective) mechanism for doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can *not* guarantee duplicate prevention by doing a select first.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Any chance you can provide an example of how to do this? The first one would be a select, but then how would I use that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a `WHERE` clause, you have to use a `SELECT` query for the data, not `VALUES`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_sync_status (ghl_contact_email, ghl_contact_data, result, wp_user_id)
        SELECT '$source->email', '$payload', 'success', $user->id
        FROM DUAL
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM contact_sync_status WHERE ghl_contact_email = '$source->email' AND wp_user_id = $user->id)";
```

But it would definitely be better to add a unique index on `(ghl_contact_email, wp_user_id)` and then use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: Now present that as a prepared statement :D

Comment: I don't feel like doing that every time I answer a SQL question. As far as I'm concerned, the comment above is sufficient.

Comment: I agree, I was jesting more than being serious. I had to actually think about how to do placeholders correctly with that kind of query above, began to self-doubt myself, ran some tests, feel better now.